Git not recognized when double click Visual Studio sln from File Explorer?
I'm having a very weird issue that surfaced after I had updated VS 2022 to 17.10.1.
If I double click to load a .SLN (solution) from File Explorer VS loads but then tells me that my solution can't find source control provider?

However, if I start VS 2022 first, and then open the solution using VS File Open, Git works fine and all is good.
So when loading my .SLN from File Explorer directly, if I select No on the remove source control dialog and open my solution.  I navigate to Git Settings and my "Git Global Settings" is blank (no user name, no email, no default location) for about 30 seconds and then automatically gets populated with the correct information.  If I navigate to "Git Repository Settings" I get the same 30 second delay and then it populates.  I kid you not!!
After I complete this, I can continue using my solution and perform all Commit/Push/Pull Git actions as I normally would.
Any suggestion on why loading an SLN directly from File Explorer vs. loading SLN from within VS 2022 behaves like this?

Have you checked your settings under Tools | Options | Source Control

@topsail Yes.  Like I said issue is not present when I load VS first and then load the project from VS.  It's really bizarre.  Even removed all extensions in case that somehow cause it, but that didn't help.

No takers?  This is still an issue, opened a support ticket with Microsoft but they provided the scripted solution, re-install the OS and VS from scratch ... yeah, not helpful.
